# React context router is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to use the context router in a component and I can't understand why it is `undefined`.
After searching for similar questions I've tried different solutions, such as:

- wrapped the `withRouter` hoc into my component
- added the `contextTypes` with `router`
- made sure that the `App` component is wrapped with `BrowserRouter`
- tried to access the `router` with both `this.props.router` and `this.context.router`

This is my code:
`index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

import { AppRedux } from 'components';
import store from './store';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <AppRedux />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

`AppRedux.js`

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import AppContainer from './AppContainer';

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  // ...
})

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  // ...
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AppContainer);
```

`AppContainer.js` - here is where I'm trying to access the context router

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

class AppContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.context) // { router: undefined }
    console.log(this.props.router) // { router: undefined }

    return (
      // ...
    );
  }
}

AppContainer.contextTypes = {
  router: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default withRouter(AppContainer);
```

Comment: You can get access to these properties in react-router: `match`, `location`, and `history`
so `this.props.router` supposed to be `undefined`
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md

Comment: Well... the first thing I should have checked is the documentation. This solved my problem.